# Entityframework single select from nested tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a problem to make a single query that doesn't take all columns from database.
Let's say i have schema:

```
table1 {
    id,
    column1,
    column2,
    column3
}

table2 {
    id,
    table1ID,
    column1,
    column2,
    column3
}
table3 {
    id,
    table2ID,
    column1,
    column2,
    column3
}
...
tableN {
    id,
    table(N-1)ID,
    column1,
    column2,
    column3
}
```

I'd like to make a linq query to select `table1.column1` and all data from `table2..tableN` structure.

Since I want all fields from `table2..tableN` I can create DTOs with corresponding fields and use AutoMapper(I don't really see a problem with that, however I've seen some discouragement online).

Solutions I know:

- I could simply take all data with `context.table1.include(table2).include(table3)..include(tableN).ToList()` and then use AutoMapper for `table2..tableN` and manually take fields I want for `table1`, but the query generated takes all the `table1` fields.
- AutoMapper in Linq doesn't work

  ```
  context.table1.select(new table1DTO {x =>
      field1 = x.field1,
      table2 = AutoMapper<table2, table2DTO>(x.table2)
  };
  ```

  This one works

  ```
  context.table1.select(x => new table1DTO {
      field1 = x.field1,
      table2 = x.table2.select(y => new table2DTO {
          field1 = y.field1,
          ..
          table3 = y.table3.select(z => new table3DTO {
              field1 = z.field1,
              ..
              table4 = ..
  )};
  ```

  but is painful to write if I have really nested structure. I could write script that would generate Linq code.
- Write two different selects, one for `table1` and other for `table2..tableN`

Do you know any better solutions?

Comment: AutoMapper has a ProjectTo method, that's the one you should use.

Answer (score 1):

with your database structure. you should create a front view with all the fields(All column of all Table) you want, and then use LINQ query.

Comment: *and then use LINQ query* Well, that's the point. How? To me, your answer isn't more than a comment.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by 'front view'

Comment: we can create a View table in Database with all column in all table. and then use Linq on this View Table.

Comment: how to create View in Transact-SQL? this my answer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx